# How to make producer idempotence in kafka cluster among two DC?

Tags: apache-kafka, cluster-computing, idempotent, producer

I have non-trival problem with kafka cluster spreaded among 2 DC. I wanna to have at the same time: 1) kafka producer idempotence and 2) async replication from DC1 to DC2. As known kafka producer idempotence require enabled acks=all in its properties. Thats requires acknoledgements from all brokers in DC1 and in DC2 too.

My question is: How I can change kafka cluster archetecture to achive ability of use idempotented producer and high aviability of brokers in DC1 and DC2? Prefering brokers from DC1.

Comment: One plain producer application cannot do this across clusters, but have you done research into how MirrorMaker2 achieves this?

Comment: It isn't work of producer - brokers instead.

Comment: I assumed DC1 and DC2 were different clusters, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Parameter `min.insync.replicas` helps solve the problem. It is mean how much replicas must saved to send ask to producer, even when `asks=all` is configured.

[link 1](https://accu.org/journals/overload/28/159/kozlovski/)
[link 2](https://www.cloudkarafka.com/blog/what-does-in-sync-in-apache-kafka-really-mean.html)

Comment: This setting alone doesn't control idempotence, only durability

Comment: It helps with indempotence in closer DC, if I set this parameter to equals to brokers amount or less, Of course, producer need ordinary settings for idempotence too.